# How to connect Heroku database from spring roo app

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, heroku, spring-roo

I have spring app deployed to heroku. I have database.properties file to kept database information. Now, I want to connect my heroku database from this properties file.

database.properties file:

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://host\:5432/dbname
database.username=username
database.password=pass
ssl=true
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

I am getting this error:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "somehost", user "someuser", database "somedb", SSL off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just playing with some settings to find how to inject this parameters:

```
ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Basically, we need to add this in databaseUrl, but in my spring roo app, it doesnt allow me to do it..

But there is another property named `connectionProperties` inside `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` bean in appcontext.xml .

applicationContext.xml:

```
 <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"></property>
```

Its working but there is one problem, When i run  my app, It takes minimum 5 minutes to startup! So i needed to increase my tomcat's timeout setting. Hope this helps someone! Cheers:)

Answer (score 2):

By default PostgreSQL denies remote connections, you must enable the remote connections. Take a look at http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/database-remote-access

Comment: Hey thanx eruiz, i have measured that, you are the one who always replies me either on linkedin or here. n truth is, we love ur gvnix.. its great effort by u to help us out:) thanx again.. Now come to my Question.. it wud be so nice,if i get little depth of your answer, I don't understand, how to and where to write that command? as per heroku docs, we need to add that ssl n sslfactory in dburl, but this prevents app to be run.

Comment: Commands on previous link is for linux. If you want the official posgreSQL information about that see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thanks Palak :) About the question, I meant it is a database server configuration issue, it isn't Spring or Spring Roo issue. You should configure PostgreSQL server to accept remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

*database.properties* is only used to fill *applicationContext.xml* values (by *context:property-placeholder* tag definition). So, if you don't modify the *dataSource* bean definition, your new properties will do nothing.

To solve your problem follow this steps:

1. Modify "database.properties" to include *datatabase.* as prefix of *ssl* and *sslfactory* property names.
2. Modify applicationContext.xml like this:

   ```
   <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
     <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
     <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
     <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
     <property name="ssl" value="${database.ssl}"/> <!-- NEW -->
     <property name="sslFactory" value="${database.sslfactory}"/> <!-- NEW -->
     <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
     ....
     ....
   </bean>
   ```

Comment: If we add that ssl and sslFactory property tags in appcontext.xml, then it will give me,  No setter found for property 'ssl' in class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource' error!

Comment: Hey thnx jmvivo.. i got it working anyway.. i have posted what i did.. thnx.